# jquery and cookies - limit the usage of search bar

Tags: jquery, cookies

I have a button that opens a Bootstrap modal which has simple search engine inside it.
When user clicks on the button, it fires a modal like this:

```
$('#search-modal').appendTo("body").modal('show');
```

But, i would like to limit the usage of search to 5 times per day per visitor.
If he tries to open the modal sixth time, instead of search modal, another one (with a message of 5 free searches per day) would open like this:

```
$('#search-limited').appendTo("body").modal('show');
```

I am complete newbie with jquery and i guess this could be done using cookies but i have no idea how to start...If anybody has any advice or can offer guideline that would be great

Update: i know that using cookies is not the best solution and that it would be better to check it on the backend but for now i am looking for most simple solution that works

Comment: You probably do not want to use cookies, if they clear their cookies they get 5 more free searches. You will want to count their searches on the back end which means you will need a way to store users and their search counts.

Comment: hi @twothreebrent, thanks for the quick reply! i know cookies are not the most ideal solution but for now i need something as simple as possible that works

Answer (score 0):

You should use [localstorage](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp), store the last date visited, and a counter